# Is there a software to create an installer from an installation process (InstallRite alternative)

Tags: windows-7, windows, installer

It's been a while since installRite has been updated and I am trying to find a newer alternative..

I need to capture the changes made to my system and create an installer from that.. I'm currently doing it manually using SystemExplorer to track changes (before and after installation) and trying build an installer piece by piece from that and it's really tasky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [Cameyo](http://www.cameyo.com/virtual-apps-for-personal), although it's more geared towards creating portable apps than installers. But it works the same: by capturing changes made during installation and making an app out of it.

[Here's](http://www.howtogeek.com/186132/how-to-create-portable-versions-of-applications-in-windows-8.1-using-cameyo/) a guide that shows how it works.